# Update Minimum Sale Quantity using the api

Tags: api, xml, inventory, magento-1.7.0.1

I've been trying to update the min sale qty field using the soap api. I can get it to update the qty and manage stock values. But can't get it to update the min sale qty or any other fields.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate xmlns="urn:Magento"><sessionId>REMOVED</sessionId>
<product>C-M1602</product>
<data>
    <qty>178</qty>
    <min_sale_qty>150</min_sale_qty>
    <use_config_min_sale_qty>0</use_config_min_sale_qty>
</data></catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know if i'm sending the wrong element name or something else i could try. I 'm hoping it's just something simple that i've missed.

The qty does update, so i know it's updating some of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up having to extend the api to achieve this. I have put my code into a git repo located here - https://github.com/bretto36/magento-stock-item-api-update